# Ĉu oni povas tajpi esperante sur aparato de PocketBook?

Tags: technology, diacritics

Mi koncideras aĉeti legilon por bitlibroj, kaj iu rekomendis al mi aparaton de „PocketBook“. Kompreneble, mi volos legi ankaŭ esperantajn librojn sur ĝi, kaj plej verŝajne, mi bezonos uzi PIV-on (aŭ alian vortaron) per la retumilo, aŭ la aparatan propran vortarprogramon (se ne ekzistas esperanta vortaro, mi eble povus krei tian).

Sed tio, kion mi ne scias kaj pri kio mi ne povas trovi informon en la retejo de [PocketBook](http://www.pocketbook-int.com/), estas ĉu oni povas tajpi la esperantajn literojn per la klavaro de la aparato. Mi demandis la helpskipon pri tio, aldone kun aliaj demandoj, sed ili nur respondis al la aliaj demandoj kaj ankaŭ diris, ke iliaj aparatoj ne havas esperantan tradukon de la interfaco (kiun mi jam sciis).

Do, ĉu iu havas aparaton „PocketBook“, kaj ĉu li aŭ ŝi scias aŭ povas kontroli ĉu eblas tajpi la esperantajn literojn sur ĝi, uzante specialan klavararanĝon aŭ iajn klavkombinojn?

Comment: Mi havas PocketBook, mi provu vespere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ne defaŭlte, sed oni povas krei kaj alŝuti novajn klavararanĝojn facile. Mi ĵus kreis esperantan aranĝon laŭ [via respondo](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/a/382/503) (q → ŝ, w → ĝ ktp.). Oni povas ĝin elŝuti [ĉi-tie](http://pastebin.com/3dCYaVSF). Oni devos tiun dosieron savi kiel `EO.kbd` en la dosierujon `system/language/keyboard`, kiu aperas post konekto al komputilo.

Jen en ago:
[image: Esperanta klavararanĝo]

[Alia versio](http://pastebin.com/aR1QcE79), pli proksima al la angla klavararanĝo:
[image: V2]

Comment: Multajn dankojn! Kio estas la modelo de via „PocketBook“?

Comment: Pro 912, sed tiu estas pli granda, ol kion la plejparto da homoj volas, preskaŭ A4. Ideale por mi, tamen.