# Kiu estas la origino de la ĉapelitaj literoj?

Tags: etymology, typography

Ĉapelitaj literoj ĉ, ĥ, ĵ, ŝ, ŭ estas sagaca rimedo, por ke ĉiu Esperanta sono estu skribita per ununura litero (unu sono, unu litero). Mi rimarkis, ke ĉ kaj ŝ havas la saman prononcon kiel la ĉeĥaj č kaj š. Ĉu tio estas nur hazarda simileco, aŭ ĉu la ĉeĥa inspiris Zamenhof en ĉi tiu okazo?

Comment: Kiel oni tajpas ilin per usona klavaro?

Comment: @MichaelHardy [Android](http://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/383/how-do-i-type-the-esperanto-letters-on-android), [Linux](http://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/378/how-do-i-type-the-esperanto-letters-with-accents-on-linux), [Mac / iOS](http://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/380/how-do-i-type-the-supersigned-esperanto-letters-mac-ios), [Windows](http://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/146/how-do-i-type-the-esperanto-letters-on-windows)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Eblas konjekti pli precize, ĉar ni havas tekstojn de pra-Esperanto (frua, ne publika versio de la lingvo) en ĝia stato je 1881. La diakritaj literoj tiutempe estis:

> **Áá / Ćć / DŹ dź / Éé / Ħħ / Óó / Śś / Ŭŭ / Źź**

El ĉi tiuj, la (malaperontaj) vokaloj estis uzataj por verbaj finaĵoj similaj al tiuj de la itala lingvo, movantaj la akcenton al la lasta silabo. La signifoj estis *-é = -as, -á = -adis, -ó = -u*.

La konsonantoj Ć, DŹ, Ś, Ź venis rekte el la pola lingvo, kie ili estas molaj versioj de la sonoj Ĉ, Ĝ, Ŝ, Ĵ (kontraste al la malmolaj CZ, DŻ, SZ, Ż). Zamenhof modifis la literojn por sennaciigi ilin, kaj por pli bone konservi la formojn de vortoj pruntotaj de okcidenteŭropaj lingvoj (ekz. *paĝo, ĵurnalo*).

La H kun trastreko, Ħ, venis miakrede el la malta lingvo, kie ĝi reprezentas senvoĉan faringan frikativon, kiu estas speco de Ĥ malofte trovebla en eŭropaj lingvoj.

La U kun hoketo, Ŭ, estas iomete mistera, sed preskaŭ certe devenis de iu cirila alfabeto, verŝajne la belorusa, kie ĝi ludas similan rolon.

Answer (score 3):

Many of the Slavic languages use similar marks over C and S, so it seems reasonable to conclude that this was the inspiration. However, Esperanto was meant to have its own, neutral alphabet, which is why the circumflex (^) was chosen. No other language uses it this way.

G and J seem to follow various pronunciations in French, English, German and other languages and do not correspond to pairs of letters in various Slavic alphabets like C and S do.

Comment: "seem to follow various pronunciations in French, English, German" -> I woud add Italian to the list, and remove German, which doesn't have the ĝ and ĵ sounds in non-loanwords.

Comment: I was thinking of the German pronunciation that mirrors the un-hatted J as in jung, ja, and Joghurt. Italian doesn't have J.

Comment: I have read somewhere the reason to go for ˆ instead of ˇ was that it's available on a French typewriter, and those were quite ubiquitous at that time – certainly more than Western Slavic ones with a háček! But somehow I couldn't find that reference ever since.

Comment: That's very interesting and worth looking in to. We shouldn't forget that we are also shaped by technology.