# How do I transform text typed with the x-system into well-formed Esperanto with ĉapeloj?

Tags: writing

Is there an online service that we can use to automatically transform this:

> *Mi mangxas mangxajxon*

into this:

> *Mi manĝas manĝaĵon*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are several, but I usually use [konvertilo from komputeko.net](http://komputeko.net/konvertilo.htm).

It's nice because it's done entirely within the browser with JavaScript so it's quick.

Answer (score 6):

Another similar tool is found on [remush.be](http://remush.be/esperanto/alunikodo.html); it has more conversion options, but also has "ux -> ŭ" on a separate button from "cx -> ĉ" etc; if you want to convert in one click you'll have to type "vx" for ŭ (this was done to preserve the "ux" in any foreign words that may be in the text, for example words from English or French).

Comment: if you want something simple, safe, and easy, try this: https://github.com/alkanadi/E-Hats

Answer (score 2):

Another tool for that is [Facililo](http://legoscia.github.io/facililo/). Its primary purpose is completely different (to classify words as "very easy" or "easy"), but incidentally it can be used to convert x-system texts as well.

(Full disclosure: I am the creator of Facililo.)

Comment: I just created an HTML program that converts the letters automatically. It is super simple and easy to use. It is free and open source. No installation required because it is written in HTML. https://github.com/alkanadi/E-Hats

Answer (score 2):

Here is an awesome tool that I just created with HTML. https://github.com/alkanadi/E-Hats. All you have to do is download E Hats.html. Then open it just like a webpage. You could even host it somewhere online (such as google docs).

There are no buttons because it converts the letters automatically. There is no installation required. Just open it in the browser like any other webpage.

It is free and open source.

Answer (score 2):

I use the extension **Ektajpu**. It's available for Chrome, Firefox, and Opera. It converts the characters as you type in the browser. It's  all JavaScript and super fast. You can install it from the [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ektajpu-esperanto-text-co/imcphpmkkohhbaipkceicfheidilofbo), the [Firefox Mozilla Add-on Store](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/ektajpu-esperanto-converter/), and the [Opera Add-on Store](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/ektajpu-esperanto-text-converter/?display=en).

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to a shell:

```
sed -e's/cx/ĉ/g' -e's/gx/ĝ/g' -e's/hx/ĥ/g' -e's/jx/ĵ/g' -e's/ux/ŭ/g' -e's/sx/ŝ/g' -e's/CX/Ĉ/g' -e's/GX/Ĝ/g' -e's/HX/Ĥ/g' -e's/JX/Ĵ/g' -e's/UX/Ŭ/g' -e's/SX/Ŝ/g'
```

Ek! ;)

Comment: Mankas ŝ! Kaj eble majuskloj.

Comment: Aldonitaj, dankon.

Answer (score 1):

An interesting service is [Traduku](http://lingvo.org/traduku), among translations and different encodings it also supports automatic “circumflexing” (typing `cx` converts to `ĉ`) as well as post-hoc conversion of a whole text.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a solution, where you can write ĉapelitojn in **any** program on your computer, there are:

- [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com) for MS Windows

  You can have a macro, that will automatically convert from x-sistemo. I have written one, which you can download from my [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4dclcm0xqs2ulxo/Esperantaj%20literoj.ahk?dl=1) (feel free to open the file in Notepad to check, that it doesn't contain any harmful macros). Note, that it contains an additional combination "Lx", which gets converted to "Linux" (otherwise "ux" would be converted to "ŭ", i.e. you would end up having "Linŭ").
- the built-in text converter for Mac

  See your Mac's documentation. Note, that a program must rely on Apple's routines in its typing system in order for this to work. There are programs, that don't do so, for instance Thunderbird doesn't do.
- [aText](https://www.trankynam.com/atext/) for Mac

  A commercial text substitution application for Mac. This works even with Thunderbird.

The main idea in all three is, that once you've set up the application to start, when you log in into your computer, you can forget its existence and just type in any program cx to get ĉ and so on.