# An US international keyboard with diacritics for more letters

Tags: technology, diacritics, typography

Recently I bought a new laptop with Windows 10 and I tried to make characters like "ĉ" and "ŭ" which I was able to do in my school Chromebook with the "US international keyboard". The thing is that the "United States-International" keyboard of my Windows device doesn't let me put diacritics in too many letters. I've been searching online and I could find the exact same keyboard that I was using in the Chromebook ([this one](https://dry.sailingissues.com/us-international-keyboard-layout.html)), but I couldn't find any way to download it.

Do you know any website where I can download that same keyboard?

Comment: Welcome to [esperanto.se] Stack Exchange! I'm not sure whether this is the right Q&A site for this question, as it seems to be about the US (English) international keyboard Layout on Windows 10, not specifically about Esperanto (or, say, a dedicated Esperanto keyboard layout).

Comment: That being said, it seems like you don't need to manually download that keyboard layout in Windows 10. It should be available from within the Keyboard Layout settings dialog. See e.g. [How to add US International Keyboard in Windows 10](https://thegeekpage.com/how-to-add-us-international-keyboard-in-windows-10/) on "The Geek Page".

Comment: The problem is that the international keyboard that is already included in my computer is not as complete as the one I used to have in my Chromebook. I can't make some Esperanto's letters with the Windows keyboard.

Comment: Did you try the solutions listed at https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/146/how-do-i-type-the-esperanto-letters-on-windows ? I especially like MSKLC (Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator), because I can create a new layout with all special characters I will ever need. If you prefer something ready to use, maybe someone else has already created a layout that fits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend [Autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/). I don't know if it works with Windows 10, since I only use a chromebook now, but when I did have a laptop (vista), it was one of my most used apps. It's actually the only thing I miss about Windows. It allows you to write your own macros & you can even go as far as writing complete applications, with a self-contained .exe for other people to use. For example you could write a script that would automatically convert 'cx' to 'ĉ', 'Cx' to 'Ĉ', etc;. Just write the script & run it (it runs in the background) & type 'cx' & it will change automatically. You can even create an option in the systray icon to toggle the script on/off with a right-click. I thought I had the script I wrote somewhere but I can't find it. It's super easy to learn though if you read the documentation.

Comment: Yes, I too strongly recommend Autohotkey, because that works for all applications. That is, once installed and set up to run at start-up with a definition file with Esperanto characters, you can forget it. You can download mine from my [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dpghu9p69fipt6d/Esperantaj%20literoj.zip?dl=1) (download begins right away. It uses the x-sistemo, but you can modify it. There is an additional combination of "Lx" for Linux. Some prefer the combination "vx" for ŭ because their language uses "ux", Some prefer a preceeding comma instead of a following x to avoid collisions.

Comment: Autohotkey works perfectly fine on Windows 10, and Notepad is all that is needed to create a simple script.

Answer (score 0):

The "same" keyboard layout (or rather, keyboard layouts of the same "name") can be different between various operating systems. Windows 10 is one operating system, but Chromebooks use a different operating system ([Chrome OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrome_OS)) by default, so some differences are to be expected.

So what are your options on Windows?

- As mentioned in [John Gordon Reid's answer](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/a/435/1576) to [How do I type the Esperanto letters on Windows?](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/q/146/1576), you may be able to modify Windows 10's US international keyboard layout (or to create a new one from scratch) to be more similar or maybe even exactly the same as the one of Chrome OS using Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator.
- If you want to be able to type characters of many different languages (especially Latin-based ones with diacritics) easily without having to switch keyboard layouts when changing between languages (and without having to memorize what character is where on which layout), a *[compose key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key#Windows)* approach may be suitable. See [Tobias Kienzler's answer](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/a/729/1576) to [How do I type the Esperanto letters on Windows?](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/q/146/1576) and [Miroslav Šedivý](https://eumiro.github.io/)'s great talk [One Brain, One Keyboard, One Editor](https://media.ccc.de/v/gpn18-98-one-brain-one-keyboard-one-editor) or his much shorter lightning talk on [Keyboard Layouts](https://youtu.be/-4QjII981sM) also covering that aspect. (Note though that Miro's instructions on how to modify the keyboard layout are specific to Linux and/or the X windowing system, and thus do not apply to Microsoft Windows.)
- Use an Esperanto keyboard layout. (Some are mentioned in answers to [How do I type the Esperanto letters on Windows?](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/q/146/1576.))
- Use additional software like Tajpi, EK, XK or TypeIt. (Many are mentioned in answers to [How do I type the Esperanto letters on Windows?](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/q/146/1576). Some don't mentione whether they work also on Windows 10.)

The New Zealand Esperanto Association has a page dedicated to [How to type Esperanto characters](https://www.esperanto.org.nz/learn-and-use-esperanto/how-to-type-esperanto-characters/) with a [sub-page focusing on Windows](https://www.esperanto.org.nz/learn-and-use-esperanto/kiel-tajpi-en-esperanto/windows/).

Answer (score 0):

You can try the **SuperLatin keyboard layout**: http://www.kreativekorp.com/software/keyboards/superlatin/

It seems to support Esperanto characters without changing anything from the base US layout, but I haven't tried it yet so I can't really endorse it.

There's EurKey too https://eurkey.steffen.bruentjen.eu/ but glancing at the documentation it seems that Esperanto is not supported.